# Where can I find list of Razor control. Example : @Html.TextBox, @Html.DropDownList

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm learning `ASP.NET MVC 4`. I'm finding documents to learn about `Razor` and `MVC`. I google and read `Razor` tutorial at `w3schools`, `codeproject` but I don't find full document to learn all about `Razor` controls and its syntax.

Can someone know where I can find it ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you're referring to the `HtmlHelper` class and all it's available extension methods - you can find those in the Extension Methods section on [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper%28v=vs.118%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The ASP.NET website has lots of good documents and walkthroughs to help with learning Razor syntax. This API Quick Reference might be what you're looking for:

http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/api-reference/asp-net-web-pages-api-reference#Classes